# Provide user option to download evaluated Google script html template as pdf via button

Tags: html, google-apps-script, pdf-generation, google-sheets-api

I'm having an issue figuring out how to add a button to html output that gives the user easy access to download a pdf copy of the html output.

Right now, users access a Google web app from my website, enter their desired options and a pre-set up username and password, and the result is html output that contains calculations based on what they entered.

Example: from the web app they select a certain course and semester, they enter their username and password, and they can view demographic data for that particular course and semester.

This is all working successfully. Data is gathered into a Google sheet from a form, and calculated in a different sheet. Each row has a user's login info, course and semester info, and the associated calculations. A Google script looks in the calc sheet for a row that matches the information the user submits, and then returns an html template with the appropriate variables evaluated.

The major problem is that users are tech novices, and dont know how to print to a pdf in their browser, or anything else. I want to put a button in their html output that allows them to download the html information as a pdf (because that's what they're comfortable with, for hard copies, etc.).

I have search every thread I could find, and I havent gotten a working solution yet for what I though would be an easy addition. And help?

Comment: `window.print()`?

Comment: Perfect, and annoyingly simple. Not familiar with how to do it, but I found a great tutorial at https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-window-print-method/amp/ in case anyone else comes looking. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps not "Perfect" as you may find that many mobiles don't support `window.print()`